# Are nested enclosures supported in Wicket, as of 1.5?

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

I've ran into some problems when using nested enclosures, and I'd like to know if it's a bug in my coding, or if the usage I'm trying is just not natively supported.

Stuff like:

```
<wicket:enclosure child="primary">
    <wicket:message key="primary.select">Primary Server</wicket:message>
    <select id="primary" wicket:id="primary"></select>
    <wicket:enclosure child="backup">
        <wicket:message key="backup.label"/>
        <span id="backup" wicket:id="backup"></span>
    </wicket:enclosure>
</wicket:enclosure>
```

The question is simply whether it's OK to use HTML like this, I want to make sure of that before I start looking for issues on the visibility controllers.

I've dug into some documentation and search engines for a while, but haven't found any mention to nested enclosures being supported, or not supported.

Thanks!

Comment: lol a year using wicket and and never used enclosures

Comment: I didn't use them for a while as well, but I'm trying to start using them, since they're just so neat.

Comment: what is the problem that you are having.  I don't know of any issues with embedded <wicket:enclosure> tags, however there are several other documented limitations to the tag

Comment: In this specific case, setting the visibility of the outer enclosure as true and the visibility of the inner one as false doesn't hide the inner enclosure, even though showing/hiding the enclosure-controlling component ("backup" component) worked fine, through the same mechanism, without the inner enclosure.

If those documented limitations you mentioned are in a centralized list somewhere, could you link them? If you do it as an answer and point out that there are no documented issues with nesting, I'll accept it, it's the kind of thing I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: i think you should use javascript ...

Comment: To have a list of documented limitation of the enclosure tag you can have a look at its javadoc http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/internal/Enclosure.html and the javadoc of EnclosureContainer http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/basic/EnclosureContainer.html.

Comment: @osdamv NEEEEVEEEEEEEEEEEEEER

Comment: @Kazaag I'd seen those, I'm not relying on onBeforeRender or validate though. I use onConfigure, which I do want to run even if the tag is invisible. But thanks anyway

Comment: I think the part saying that tag enclosures are sibling (in the component tree) of the its child (on the html) is probably the issue.  In your case the 2 enclosure are in fact sibling so it can prevent them to work correctly.  Can you wrap the inner enclosure in a WebMarkupContainer (use the wicket:container as tag) to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for such a late response, I hadn't seen your comment.

I don't believe that there are any documented limitations related to nesting <wicket:enclosure> tags; however, there are a few other limitations to the tag that have been documented.

The first limitation is documented in the [Wicket tag doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/wickets-xhtml-tags.html#Wicket%2527sXHTMLtags-Elementwicket%253Aenclosure):

> Changing the visibility of a child component in Ajax callback method will not affect the entire enclosure but just the child component itself. This is because only the child component is added
>   to the AjaxRequestTarget.

and

> If there is more than one wicket component directly underneath the enclosure, you have to specify which one controls the visibility by providing its id in the enclosure's child attribute:

And second, there is a closed [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-2541) regarding hiding FormComponents using a <wicket:enclosure> tag.  Basically any FormComponent hidden by the tag will still be validated on Form submission.  If you watch your logs, there is a warning message given for this issue.

**Note:** The term "Documented" for Wicket is somewhat ambiguous.  I suppose you just have to get used to piecing together information from various sources in order to find answers to your questions.  When in doubt, try to find the javadoc or inline comments for the source code.  Those are usually the best documented sources.